# Setting up loop in Excel VBA to repeatedly sum up specific number of rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have excel sheet like that and I want to sum up value of each country and write and store in front of each country in column C, it means I have to have same amount in front of each country. I have to do that globally. Can someone help me to that using VBA of excel?

[image: excel sheet]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in column C:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,A1,B:B)
```

Comment: oh nice thank you, but could you help how to write in VBA?

Comment: `MsgBox WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Range("A1"), Range("B:B"))`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub AddTotals()

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rg = sht.Range("C1")
    n = rg.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    rg.Resize(n, 1).Value = "=SUMIF(A:A,A1,B:B)"

End Sub
```